# Can an existing website's Membership security be accessed by Winforms app in C# .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, encryption, asp.net-membership

This might be two questions, but I'm not sure. More experienced Membership users than me should be able to advise me on whether I should split it into two.

I have a website that connects to an SQL Server database to provide security via the .Net Membership classes, and what I want to do is have a Winforms application to administrate user accounts.

In addition, I don't want to store unencrypted connection strings into App.config, which is what I presume I will need to do, but what I'm hoping is that there's a standard way to encrypt them.

What I have done up until now is to manually encrypt and decrypt them using System.Security.Cryptography classes.

What I need to know is:

1. How do I set up a Winforms application to use my website's Membership security?
2. How do I encrypt the connection strings within App.config?

Answer (score 0):

The following suppose that you have the control in the deployment of the database, the website.

For a Winforms application and depending your database, but let assume that it is SQL SERVER, you should use integrated security and let Windows do this dirty job.

If you can't use integrated security (client are not on the same domain than the database), you should ask the user to insert their credential on first use, store theses data in a secure place and build the connection string by hand. Have a look to the ProtectedData Class and the Data Protection API (DPAPI) for storing these kind of data.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata(v=vs.110).aspx

For a website application, you could use database integrated security too with the credential of the IIS User or with the client windows authentication if they have one. As the config file of the website should not be visible to the client it is not the biggest security issue if it contains some credential.

As I'm not a guru of ASP.Net, you should not rely only on my experience.